# Python C build: "undefined symbol" errror, when code runs using gcc directly

Tags: python, c, mongodb, gcc, python-c-api

I have a python extension written in c which compiles fine however barfs

```
ImportError: /path/to/cmongo.so: undefined symbol: json_tokener_parse
```

When I try to import the module (`import cmongo`) in python.

What makes this strange is the the c compiles AND RUNS fine using gcc directly:

```
gcc --std=c99 cmongo.h json2bson.c  cmongo.c -lmongoc -ljson -o mong_test
./mong_test
# test main function prints stuff as required.
```

The extension worked find before adding the `json2bson.c` file and calls.

Both libraries (`mongoc` and `json`) and the extra compiler arg `--std=c99` are included in setup.py, so I'm assuming the problem is either the plethora of other arguments python passes to gcc or a need to somehow reference json-c when importing the shared libary. However this is beyond my understanding of such things.

I know external links are frowned up, but to avoid a massive question while still providing a full explanation of the problem I've put all the relevant files in [a gist](https://gist.github.com/samuelcolvin/7489282).

Comment: In the gist, `json_tokener_parse` is only called and never defined.  Obviously it cannot work.  Maybe the function that contains it is not needed for `mong_test`?

Comment: `json_tokener_parse` is defined, it's defined [in json-c](https://github.com/json-c/json-c/blob/master/json_tokener.h) which is included in `json2bson.c` via `json.h`. I'm also sure it's called in the test function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it at last!

Turns out I needed :

```
libraries = ['json-c', 'mongoc'],`
```

in setup.py instead of

```
libraries = ['json', 'mongoc'],
```

Seems weird to me since gcc worked with `-lmongoc -ljson` (gcc also works with `-lmongoc -ljson-c` too as it happens). I guess it's something to do with the way they parse library names - eg. gcc assumed everthing after a `-` is part of the version number extra so `json` is considered the same as `json-c`???

For reference

```
ldd <library_name>.so
```

Helped a lot.